# How can I group data scraped from multiple pages, using Scrapy, into one Item?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to collect a few pieces of information about a bunch of different web sites. I want to produce one `Item` per site that summarizes the information I found across that site, regardless of which page(s) I found it on.

I feel like this should be an item pipeline, like the [duplicates filter](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#duplicates-filter) example, except I need the final contents of the `Item`, not the results from the first page the crawler examined.

So I tried using [`request.meta`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#passing-additional-data-to-callback-functions) to pass a single partially-filled `Item` through the various `Request`s for a given site. To make that work, I had to have my parse callback return exactly one new `Request` per call until it had no more pages to visit, then finally return the finished `Item`. Which is a pain if I find multiple links I want to follow, and breaks entirely if the scheduler throws away one of the requests due to a link cycle.

The only other approach I can see is to dump the spider output to json-lines and post-process it with an external tool. But I'd prefer to fold it into the spider, preferably in a middleware or item pipeline. How can I do that?

Comment: How about this ugly solution? Define a dictionary (defaultdict(list)) on a pipeline for storing per-site data. In process_item you can just append a dict(item) to the list of per-site items and raise DropItem exception. Then, in `close_spider` method, you can dump the data to whereever you want. Sorry, if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Hey @AlexanderAfanasiev, interesting approach! I hadn't considered using the item pipeline's `close_spider` method. I think that could work. I'm hoping someone will propose a cleaner approach, but if you'd add your suggestion as an answer I'll probably accept it in a couple days. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, I've added the comment as an answer. If it doesn't work, consider providing the code of your spider. Thanks.

Comment: hey Jamey Sharp, I am in same situation, how did you ended up solving your problem?, thanks

Comment: @JoeCabezas, I don't think I ever did find a solution I was satisfied with... but I think at some point Scrapy changed to provide both success and error callbacks, which I think means you can ensure that your spider keeps running even if some of your requests get dropped, making the `request.meta` approach more practical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this ugly solution?

Define a dictionary (defaultdict(list)) on a pipeline for storing per-site data. In process_item you can just append a dict(item) to the list of per-site items and raise DropItem exception. Then, in close_spider method, you can dump the data to whereever you want.

Should work in theory, but I'm not sure that this solution is the best one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want summary, Stats Collection would be another approach
http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.16/topics/stats.html

for example:

to get total page crawled in each of websites. use the following code.

```
stats.inc_value('pages_crawled:%s'%socket.gethostname())
```

Comment: I'm not simply trying to count things, so I don't think this approach meets my needs. It is interesting and not something I'd considered, though; thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had same issues when i was writing my crawler.

I solved this issue by passing a list of urls through meta tag and chaining them together.

[Refer to detailed tutorial I wrote here.](https://sickyoon.com/2016/how-to-combine-data-from-multiple-web-pages-in-web-crawler-scrapy/)